# Conditional rendering after function - VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I am currently writing a template for sending an email and after the function I want to conditionally render a success or error block. For some reason it is not working. The function itself is working, however neither success or error block is rendered. Please find my code below.

Template:

```
<form v-if="success==null" @submit.prevent="sendEmail" >
     ... //form code
    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn" value="send" />                                        
</form>
<b-alert variant="success" v-if="success">success</b-alert>
<b-alert variant="error" v-if="!success">error</b-alert>
```

Function:

```
   data() {
        return {
            success: null
        }
    },
    methods: {

    sendEmail: (e) => {
        ... // request code
        .then((result) => {
            this.success=true
            console.log('success')
        }, (error) => {
            this.success=false
            console.log('error')
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Use :key and v-else

Comment: What value should I give for :key?

Comment: the variable that's responsible for changing/rendering the elements. But be careful to not use duplicate keys for more than one element. Try my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to use strict comparing for error block
like:

```
success === false
```

There can be problems with `!success` because it's `true` for both `null` and `false`.

Also you can use `string` instead of `boolean|null`

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    type: 'form',
    formData: {
      email: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sendEmail() {
      if (this.formData.email) {
        this.type = 'success';
      } else {
        this.type = 'error';
      }

      setTimeout(() => this.type = 'form', 10000);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.success {
  color: green;
}

.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <form v-if="type === 'form'" @submit.prevent="sendEmail">
    <input type="email" v-model="formData.email" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>

  <div v-if="type === 'success'" class="success">Success!</div>
  <div v-if="type === 'error'" class="error">Error!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Are you sure your success/error handler are called ?/
2. In your method sendEmail you should define define it without an arrow function

```js
sendEmail (e) {
       ... // request code
       .then((result) => {
           this.success=true
           console.log('success')
       }, (error) => {
           this.success=false
           console.log('error')
       })
   }
```

Comment: 1.Yes, the logs are printed in the console
2. Okay, I'll change it, thanks

Comment: Okay I think the arrow function could have been the problem, it looks better now. But why?

Comment: @coffee-and-code because VueJS use this to refer to the component. When you write an arrow function you lose the this

Comment: @BabacarCisséDia `this` will work fine there. Arrow function gets context of the place where it's  defined, so this arrow function will get sendEmail context. 
If you'll pass `function() {}` it'll have it's own context with wrong `this`

Comment: @coffee-and-code It's better to use arrow functions there.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<b-alert :variant="success ? 'success' : 'error'" v-if="success!=null" :key="success">
   <span v-if="success">success</span>
   <span v-else>error</span>
</b-alert>
```